# c: linked list: how to write a node swapping function?

Tags: c, linked-list

here's my function:

```
void switchnodes(NODE **A)
{
    if((*A)->next)
    {
        NODE *first = pop(A);
        NODE *second = pop(A);
        push(A,first);
        push(A,second);
    }
}
```

push and pop:

```
void push(NODE **top,NODE *nnew)
{
    nnew->next=*top;
    *top=nnew;
}
NODE * pop(NODE **top)
{
    NODE *remove = *top;
    *top=(*top)->next;
    remove->next=0;
    return remove;
}
```

my confusion:

NODE:

```
typedef struct node {
    int value;
    struct node *next;
} NODE;
```

`NODE * top` my linked list holding values 1...10
`NODE * holder` is another pointer pointing to the 5th and 4th node of the linked list, respectively

`switchnodes(&holder);` holder pointing to the 5th node. The 6th node gets lost
`switchnodes(&(holder->next));`holder pointing the 4th node. 5th and 6th nodes successfully swapped.

why does that happen?

and how do I write this function so I don't have to pass pointer->next? I can't do that in every instance, like if its the top node I need to swap.

Comment: First question to ask, do you *have* to swap the nodes rather than their values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the way your list works: You can only swap nodes via `next` pointers; `holder` is a pointer outside the list. It may get updated, but the list won't know.

Say `holder` points to the 4th node. You swap it, it now points to the new 4th node, the former 5th node. But what's important: The `next` pointer of the list's third node still points to the 4th node - 4th before swapping that is.

You can make your list two-way by having a haed and a tail and an additional `prev` pointer for each node. Then you can use that information to update the swapped nodes' neighbours, if any.

Answer (score 1):

You have to update first's "next" at switchnodes function. Here is a working function:

```
void switchnodes(NODE **A)
{
    if((*A)->next)
    {
        NODE *first = pop(A);
        NODE *second = pop(A);  
        push(A,first);
        first->next = second->next; //the missing line
        push(A,second);
    }
}
```

Comment: This function didn't work for me. I used exactly as described in the OP